# confusing where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I want to have a simple condition in my where clause, on one of the columns like:

When `@PostTypeid is null` then **where** should be `PostTypeid in (4,5)` and if
`@PostTypeid  is not null` then where clause should be `PostTypeId = @PostTypeId`

I am trying to use **case** for this purpose but I think I am getting confused with the syntax. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
 (PostTypeid = case(@PostTypeId) when null then in (4,18) else @PostTypeId end)
```

The error is when I use **in**, I dont think that's a valid syntax. What is the correct way to do this? thanks. I Tried shifting the braces to several other places but in vain.

Thanks

Comment: I even used ``(case(@PostTypeId) when null then PostTypeId in (4, 18) else PosttypeId = @PostTypeId end)`` and sql didnt like that at all!

Comment: Your logic does not make sense. @PostTypeid can be null and 4 at the same time?

Comment: @gbn: if either 4 or 18 is passed, then i need to select posts in that type id, if nothing is passed (null is passed), i want to select posts from both id. Does my logic say it can be null and 4 at the same time? I cant see it (prolly because of the beer i had yesterday) can you please explain more?

Comment: "When @PostTypeid is null then where should be @PostTypeid in (4,5)" = ambiguous

Comment: @gbn: Ah, I see it now, my mistake it is. corrected it now. Thanks much! I typed the code here hence the error. I should have copy pasted the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
WHERE
    (@PostTypeID IS NULL AND PostTypeId IN (4, 5)) OR
    (@PostTypeId IS NOT NULL AND PostTypeID = @PostTypeID)
```

perhaps?

Comment: d'oh! facepalm! why didn't I think of that! Thank you Matt! I guess I was obsessed with solving the problem with **case**. silly me (or silly the beer that I had yesterday - I think I had one too many!)

Comment: There is a slight mismatch of braces in your code Mr. Matt, its supposed to be ``((@PostTypeID IS NULL AND PostTypeId IN (4, 18)) OR (@PostTypeId IS NOT NULL AND PostTypeID = @PostTypeID))`` but I am sure you meant it to be this. thanks much!

Comment: oh but ofcourse, I didn't mention i have other conditions in my clause and this is just one of them, so your code is perfect if that was the only condition, my mistake, sorry!

Answer (score -2):

You cant use = and in operators in one statement

EDIT:

(PostTypeid **=** case(@PostTypeId) when null then **in** (4,18) else @PostTypeId end)

if the @PostTypeId is null then it will goes like this.

```
(PostTypeid = in (4,8))
```

and this is syntax error.

```
case(@PostTypeID) when IS NULL then PostyTypeId in (4,18) else PostTypeId = PostTypeId
```

this case should return single result.

Comment: can you please explain further?

Comment: Hi, I already tried this version before I posted here. Infact, if you see my comment on my question, I have mentioned it already. this doesn't work at all.

Comment: I was not sure about this ether, but you have the answer. So problem solved. ;-). And also I made a typo instead of cant i wrote can... that explain those two down votes.

Comment: out of those two downvotes, one is mine and yes, it was because of "can" instead of cant. now I cant take the downvote off, can you please edit and add a space in there somewhere so I can take the downvote off? thanks and sorry!